# How to convert ML model to MLlib model?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I had trained Machine Learning models using Spark RDD based API (mllib package) 1.5.2 say "Mymodel123",

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel Mymodel123 = ....;
Mymodel123.save("sparkcontext","path");
```

Now I'm using Spark Dataset based API (ml package) 2.2.0 . Is there any way to load the models (Mymodel123) using Dataset based API?

```
org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel newModel =  org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.load("sparkcontext","path");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API that can do that, however you `RandomForestModels` wrap old `mllib` API and [provide `private` methods](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0698e6c88ca11fdfd6e5498cab784cf6dbcdfacb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/DecisionTreeClassifier.scala#L287-L299) which can be used to convert `mllib` models to `ml` models:

```
/** Convert a model from the old API */
private[ml] def fromOld(
    oldModel: OldRandomForestModel,
    parent: RandomForestClassifier,
    categoricalFeatures: Map[Int, Int],
    numClasses: Int,
    numFeatures: Int = -1): RandomForestClassificationModel = {
  require(oldModel.algo == OldAlgo.Classification, "Cannot convert RandomForestModel" +
    s" with algo=${oldModel.algo} (old API) to RandomForestClassificationModel (new API).")
  val newTrees = oldModel.trees.map { tree =>
    // parent for each tree is null since there is no good way to set this.
    DecisionTreeClassificationModel.fromOld(tree, null, categoricalFeatures)
  }
  val uid = if (parent != null) parent.uid else Identifiable.randomUID("rfc")
  new RandomForestClassificationModel(uid, newTrees, numFeatures, numClasses)
}
```

so it is not impossible. In Java you can use it directly (Java doesn't respect package private modifiers), in Scala you'll have to put adapter code in `org.apache.spark.ml` package.